# Ways to influence the readers subconscious?

Tags: technical-writing, technique

Are there any proven techniques of influencing the readers on a subconscious level? Preferably techniques involving only words as I'm interested in writing technical books and I don't have the liberty of using fancy images, styles, etc...

I'm looking more precisely for ways to:

1. help readers better memorize technical data
2. influence the readers to accept ideas on a subconscious level
3. build good memories in a readers subconscious about the book

Any good readings/studies on the topic?

Comment: I read something about this once doing graduate work. Wikipedia led me to Watanabe "Perceptual Disturbances without Perception." __Nature__ 413. It wasn't too long.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 - Our brains remember things by association. If you associate the technical data with strong examples or stories, the readers will be more likely to remember the details.

Question 2 - Not sure how ethical that is.  Just give them the information.  There are always going to be people that disagree with you... Don't worry about them.

Question 3 - You're talking about manipulating people and generally people don't like that.  Just write a good book that you would enjoy yourself and don't worry about the rest.  If you're trying to get people to believe some kind of propaganda, just tell the truth and let them decide for themselves.

And some thoughts - Within the past year or so I've gone through a number of training courses from FEMA and also ethics in government purchasing.  These courses were very detailed and full of technical words which were severely overused to the point of becoming meaningless.  I still cringe when I hear the word, "applicable."  They were dry, boring, mind numbing courses, written by committee and edited by lawyers, and I remember almost nothing from them.

If you want to present technical data and have an influence on people that goes beyond just reporting the data, then using a natural, conversational style that is pleasant for the reader to read will be of the most use to you.